# How to reuse Hashtable

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to execute the following code snippet:

```
    connectionMap = new Hashtable<Directions, Room>();
    connectionMap.put(Directions.SOUTH, corr);
    hall.setMap(connectionMap);

    connectionMap.clear();
    connectionMap.put(Directions.SOUTH, dining);
    corr.setMap(connectionMap);
```

I notice that all rooms end up getting the last value of connection map despite clearing it before setting up each Room. Can someone please explain what might be causing this? Creating a new map at every point apprears to be a bad coding style. Are there better solutions?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you think `clear` does? What do you think `connectionMap` is referencing?

Comment: _Creating a new map at every point apprears to be a bad coding style._ Why do you think so?

Comment: Perhaps a `Map` (or `Hashtable`) isn't the best data structure for your specific problem. If you explain what you're trying to do, you can get better answers.